# Any way/API to get the list of documentIds in the envelope

Tags: rest, docusignapi, docusignconnect

We are working on POC to integrate our public API with DocuSign using Webhook Connect.

Want to know is there any way/API by which we can get the Document IDs of all the documents in an envelope, we don't want documents to be included in the payload of webhook notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a call to list the documents in an envelope and the ID of each document is contained in the response. The call follows this format:

/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents

Here's a [link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/list/) to the DocuSign Developer center with more information.